# How to pass listbox data from form1 to form2 with a button click

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have two Windows Forms. I have read data from the database and load data into `Listbox1` on `Form1(FrmSelection)`. Now what i want is, when a user select a value from `Listbox1` on `Form1` and click process button, the selected value must be loaded on `Form2(FrmProcessOrder) Listbox2`. I have tried different examples but am not get it to work. here are the steps below

1.Run Application

2.FrmSelection Opens with empty listbox,then click process button which opens   FrmSelection

3.FrmSelections opens up,this form contains one listbox and data the i have read from the database.

4.Select one item from the listbox

5.Click Addforms button after selecting the item from listbox on FrmSelections.

6. Selected item must appear on FrmProcessorder listbox.

Problem - Am getting error on FrmProcessorder form when i click Addforms button after selecting the item(object not set to an instance of an object)

here is my code below..

Form1(FrmSelection)

```
    public partial class FrmProcessOrder : Form
{

    public FrmProcessOrder()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
    }
    private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program._FrmSelection = new FrmSelection();
        Program._FrmSelection.Show();
    }

    public void AddList(ListBox _Listing)
    {
        ListBoxForms.Items.AddRange(_Listing.Items); 
    }
}
```

Form 2(FrmProcessOrder )

```
   FrmProcessOrder _FrmProcessOrder;
    public FrmSelection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadData();
    }

    //Method which reads data from the db and laod data on listview
    public void LoadData()
    {
        _connection = "Data Source=MILESTONE-PC;Initial Catalog=Jack;Integrated Security=True";
        _sql = "Select * from tblJackon";
        _conn = new SqlConnection(_connection);
        _conn.Open();

        _comm = new SqlCommand(_sql, _conn);
        _adapt.SelectCommand = _comm;
        _adapt.Fill(_dataset, _sql);
        DataTable _tbl = _dataset.Tables[0];
        _dtrow = null;

        foreach (DataRow _dataVariable in _tbl.Rows)
        {
            _dtrow = _dataVariable;
            ListBoxSelection.Items.Add((_dtrow["FormNames"]));
        }
    }

    private void btnAddForms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _FrmProcessOrder.AddList(ListBoxSelection);  // It throws error on this line after select from listbox so that the item must to FrmProcessOrder listbox
        _FrmProcessOrder = new FrmProcessOrder();    
    }
```

Comment: FrmProcessOrder does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. Can you try moving the code so that You load the data after you load the form?

Comment: I have updated the code and added some explanations to make it more clear.

Comment: can you show the error please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit (after the question is edited):**

Check this:

FrmProcessOrder _FrmProcessOrder; //no object declared

```
private void btnAddForms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _FrmProcessOrder.AddList(ListBoxSelection);  // This is null exception
    _FrmProcessOrder = new FrmProcessOrder(); //it should not be put here
}
```

Your `_FrmProcessOrder` is used before it is initialized properly. Do this instead:

```
FrmProcessOrder _FrmProcessOrder = new FrmProcessOrder(); //Now it is declared, only once

private void btnAddForms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _FrmProcessOrder.AddList(ListBoxSelection);  // Now it should be ok
}
```

---

**Original:**

One of the simplest way would be to put your input as a field (or create a method call to do it) rather than as a constructor argument.

Change this:

```
public FrmProcessOrder(ListBox _List)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListBoxForms2.Items.AddRange(_List.Items);         
}
```

Into this

```
public FrmProcessOrder()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void AddList(ListBox _List){
    ListBoxForms2.Items.AddRange(_List.Items);         
}
```

Then when you could call your `Form` Method whenever you need

```
_FrmProcessOrder.AddList(listBox);
```

Comment: I must add this code(_FrmProcessOrder.AddList(listBox) under selection form button?

Comment: @JuniorLinq no, you need to call it after you create the `form`. For instance if you create it: `FrmProcessOrder _FrmProcessOrder = new FrmProcessOrder();` in your `FrmSelection`. Then after it is created, before it is used, you could call `_FrmProcessOrder.AddList(listBox);`

Comment: Am confused. ..can you show me in code you posted.  I tried what you said but it is not working.

Comment: Am getting object reference not set to an instance of an object error under the button on FrmSelection

Comment: @JuniorLinq "Am getting object reference not set to an instance of an object error under the button on FrmSelection" perhaps it is best if you could show this new code.

Comment: I have updated the code and added some explanations to make it more clear.

Comment: @JuniorLinq I have updated my answer. It seems to be null exception error. Check it out. ;)

Comment: It is not adding on form process order Listbox. i have put break point and i can see the selected item but it is not showing on Frmprocessorder listbox... we are almost there only one step left

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
Application.Run(new FrmProcessOrder());
```

you're trying to instantiate a new `FrmProcessOrder`, but you have one constructor like this:

```
public FrmProcessOrder(ListBox _List)
```

so you can't instantiate without a parameter `ListBox`.
If you want this you have to add to `Form1` the empty constructor:

```
public FrmProcessOrder()
{

}
```

Comment: I have updated the code and added some explanations to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have wrongly copied the code blocks(swapped Form2 & Form1).

This line `Application.Run(new FrmProcessOrder());` should be replaced by `Application.Run(new FrmSelection());` which would load the data from the database.

The compilation error you are seeing is since you do not have an empty constructor. As per the current code, to instantiate 'FrmProcessOrder' you have to provide an instance of ListBox.

Comment: I have updated the code and added some explanations to make it more clear.